# gnu make rebuild if any of the requisites down the line changed

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm currently running into a problem using gnu make where I have the following setup in the makefile: (only the parts that matter)

```
all: bin/game

bin/game: obj/main.o
    gcc -o bin/game obj/main.o

obj/main.o: src/main.cpp
    gcc -c src/main.cpp -o obj/main.o

# Don't do anything, just make sure that library.hpp hasn't changed
src/main.cpp: include/library.hpp

# Don't do anything, just make sure that part1 and part2 haven't changed
include/library.hpp: include/library/part1.hpp\
                     include/library/part2.hpp
```

And in this long spiral of requisites, which has many more object files, source files and header files in the actual project, although it rebuilds `bin/game` when I update src/main.cpp, when I update `include/library/part1.hpp`, `include/library/part2.hpp` or even `include/library.hpp`, it doesn't rebuild `bin/game`, even though it depends on it.

Is it because make ignore the requisites of src/main.cpp because it itself hasn't changed?

I've noticed that moving `include/library.hpp` to the `obj/main.o` requisites fixed this particular problem, although it still doesn't update when either `include/library/part1.hpp` or `include/library/part2.hpp` are changed.

**Is there a way to separate the recipe into 'levels' the way I'm doing in here to make things more organized rather than listing them all in a target?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`src/main.cpp: include/library.hpp` tells make to rebuild `src/main.cpp` when `include/library.hpp` has changed. This is incorrect, since what you build is `obj/main.o`. Fix:

```
obj/main.o : include/library.hpp
```

---

Next, since you do not build `include/library.hpp` or `src/main.cpp`, their dependencies are useless. Fix:

```
obj/main.o : include/library.hpp include/library/part1.hpp include/library/part2.hpp
```

---

In practice, you do not want to have to specify header dependencies yourself because that is tedious and error-prone. The compiler can do that for you:

```
obj/main.o: src/main.cpp
    gcc -c src/main.cpp -o obj/main.o -MD -MP
-include obj/main.d # produced by -MD -MP
```

And drop those lines with `src/main.cpp : ...` and `include/library.hpp : ...`.

You can inspect `obj/main.d` and see all files `obj/main.o` depends on.

On the first build you do not need header dependencies because it has to build everything (`-include obj/main.d` doesn't fail if `obj/main.d` doesn't exist). On subsequent builds it uses the dependencies generated by the previous build to decide what needs to be rebuilt.

Comment: Thank you, I think I've understood, I did not know of the .d files beforehand, so I thought I had to manually type every single dependency and I wanted a way to ease that by stretching it out over various targets, but this works even better.